# How to express power law as a differential equation, while not being a function of absolute time?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, exponentiation

The data I have can nicely be described by a power law

$$y=a*t^{-b} + c$$

I need to come up with a differential equation, which the above equation is a solution to. This can be expressed as

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{-b*y}{t}$$

However, I need to figure out a time-relative expression, i.e. the above is a function of time t and state variable y, whereas I need it only as a function of state variables y[n].

The use case is to have a mechanistical model, showing the behavior under different circumstances. Intuitively, I think it might lead to a space vector of "memory" states or partial derivative, but cant figure out the math.

Thanks for any leads!
F/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure of your question but
$$y=a*t^{-b} + c$$
becomes after the first derivative
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = -b at^{-b-1} = -\frac{b}{t}(y - c)
$$
to get rid of $t$ you can use the fact
$$
t^{-b} = \frac{y-c}{a} \to t = \left(\frac{y-c}{a}\right)^{-1/b}
$$
or
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = -b at^{-b-1} = -b(y - c)\left(\frac{y-c}{a}\right)^{1/b} = -\frac{b}{a^{1/b}} \left(y-c\right)^{1 + \frac{1}{b}}
$$

Comment: Thank you, that little trick of eq3 is just perfect, haven't though of it myself!